# Load facebook comments plugin Async

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I am using facebook comments plugin in my site and it seems to me, that the plugin loads up when the page is loaded completely which I do not desire.

I have a lot of pictures on my page, and page is taking some time to fully load up. So i want the facebook comments to load even the page is still in progress.

Added this right after the body tag.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4&appId=ID";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Added that where i want to comments to appear.

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="{{ blog.share_url }}"
                     data-version="v2.3"
                     data-width="100%" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

### Tried

Setting js.async = false;

Again, when the page load is complete, the comments plugin is visible after that.
Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After months of research I am able to find the solution.

```
FB.XFBML.parse();
```

Will load your comments even if the page loading has not been completed.

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({appId: '1422501874658917', version: 2.4, xfbml: true});

        // *** here is my code ***
        if (typeof facebookInit == 'function') {
            facebookInit();
        }
    };

    (function () {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());


    function facebookInit() {
        console.log('Found FB: Loading comments.');
        FB.XFBML.parse();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just set async = false. This makes it blocking which will keep the pictures from loading until the comments have loaded. It also depends how you call the js file which loads the images. I prefer placing it at the bottom to make sure all html elements have loaded first.

Comment: setting js.async = false did not work. the page loads completely before the comments plugin to be visible. I have added the script right after opening the body tag, that what the official doc says.